# Missconfigures Django settings, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DeveloperRoad'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm making a django blog app and  I created a Custom User, modifying the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` constant in the settings.py file.

But the database drop an  IntegrityError, so I though it was that the configuration file wasn't being imported, and  I did the following command,with `virtualenv` activated:

```py
 export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=DeveloperRoad.settings
```

My project app is named `DeveloperRoad` and the settings file is `settings`,so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My project structure is the following:

```sh
DeveloperRoad

├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── blog
│   │       ├── add_category.html
│   │       ├── add_post.html
│   │       ├── author.html
│   │       ├── categories.html
│   │       ├── categories_list.html
│   │       ├── delete_post.html
│   │       ├── details.html
│   │       ├── edit_post.html
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── extra_filters.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── DeveloperRode
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── members
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── backends.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── registration
│   │       ├── login.html
│   │       └── singup.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py

├── static
│   ├── css

└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── footer.html
    ├── Login.html
    ├── navbar.html
    └── Register.html
```

Now that I try to run the server I get this error, relationated with the settings:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DeveloperRoad'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 343, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 232, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 226, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DeveloperRoad'
```

What Can I do?

Comment: In your file structure, the module looks like it's called `DeveloperRode`, not `DeveloperRoad`

Comment: Yeah, It was a typo!